# MVC e DAO - Regras de Dados

Tags: mvc, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, regra-de-negócio

Em um CRUD onde no ato do cadastro deve-se verificar se determinado campo já existe no banco, à fim de não permitir cadastro duplicado, esta regra de verificação deve estar na classe DAO (`Exception` caso exista no ato do cadastro) ou *Controller* (consultar via DAO que retorna `true` ou false antes do cadastro)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é sempre muito polêmico, cada um tem uma opinião. Algumas pessoas gostam do [modelo anêmico](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) aí vão falar para colocar no controlador. Mas isso é um erro conceitual. O correto é no modelo.

O controlador servirá como intermediário para a visão falar com o modelo. A visão é a consumidora e que iniciará a chamada da validação.

Toda inteligência de dados deve estar no modelo, eu acho.

Veja mais em [No Ruby on Rails a regra de negócio fica no model?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165925/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas acontece que todos os cadastros estão no banco, não na Model. a Model representa uma única tupla..

Comment: Pois da maneira que fiz, A controll conversa com a DAO e com a Model. e não a Model conversa com a DAO.

Comment: O que inclusive gerou esta dúvida, tanto comigo como com outros amigos , se quem conversa com a DAO é a Model ou a Controll.. pois um professor utiliza de um jeito e outro de outro!

Comment: Você precisaria colocar como está feito. O modelo é para ser uma representação do que está no DB. Eu não acho isso certo (mas tem gente que acha), aí se está errado, pra mim faz pouca diferença quem faz o que. Claro que pode fazer isso e estar certo, mas eu não sei, não vi nada como está.

Comment: Mas para isso estar na Model eu obrigatoriamente teria que definir que quem faz a comunicação com a DAO seria a Model, certo? Pois da maneira que fiz (não sei se é mau uso) quem envia o objeto para persistência via DAO é o Control e não a Model. Ou seja, a Model não sabe que a DAO existe.

Comment: Aí é que tá, certo e errado depende de contexto. Só porque alguém disse não quer dizer que é uma coisa ou outra. Teria que ver o caso concreto. Tem gente que faz como está falando, tem gente que fica horrorizado com isso.

Comment: Mas partindo do pressuposto de sua resposta e da resposta do Cigano, que cabe a Model fazer tal controle, seria inevitável a relação do Model com a DAO, pois isso não seria possível via Control. Porque como a Model faria tal controle sabendo que ela representa apenas uma instância? (Estou pensando em Java)

Comment: No meu entendimento sim. Eu acho que se o controlador falar com o DAO, não é MVC.

Answer (score 2):

## Na DAO não. No Model.

Conceitualmente falando, por se tratar de uma regra de conjuntos (um campo não pode se repetir entre as entidades), o ideal é se definir em *Model*, ainda que nem todos os *frameworks* possuam este recurso.

Em ASP.NET MVC, por exemplo, a unicidade pode ser definida da seguinte forma:

```cs
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public String Nome { get; set; }
```

Se o *framework* não possui esta capacidade, a verificação da já existência do registro com uma determinada condição pode ser feita pelo *Controller*. O Laravel, por exemplo, invoca a validação em *Controller*:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'titulo' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'conteudo' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Mas acontece que todos os cadastros estão no banco, não na Model. a Model representa uma única tupla..

Comment: Exato. Falando de teoria, a unicidade é uma questão um pouco mais tecnológica do que conceitual, então cada *framework* implementa isso à sua maneira. Quando você fala que "os cadastros estão no banco", está sim falando que os cadastros estão no *Model*, porque o *Model* é a representação em sistema de uma base de dados. No MVC não existe separação entre banco e *Model*.